# Check if strings are x% equal

Tags: php, javascript, string, comparison

I want to compare three strings:

```
"a text string" //target string
"a kind of similar text string"
"the cow jumps over the moon"
```

And set a percentage parameter that returns the results that are x% similar to the target.

```
$results = compare($array,$target,80)

$results // Returns an array with str 1,2, because they are at least 80 similar to the target.
```

Also, is a similar function possible in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: +1 - same reason as in my comment below.

Comment: @KristerAndersson: `compare` isn't actually a PHP function.

Comment: @Rocket - No I meant the `similar_text`, became a little confused, though I was writing my comment to you. Anyway the question is good so +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP, there is the function [`similar_text`](http://php.net/similar_text). As for JavaScript, there's the [PHP.js project](http://phpjs.org), which re-implements PHP functions in JavaScript. They have an implementation of [`similar_text`](http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text:902) you can use.

The JavaScript implementation doesn't support the percent parameter, it seems.

Comment: Is it possible in Javascirpt?

Comment: @Derek: Anything's possible.  I didn't look too much, but you maybe able to find an implementation out there.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php).

It takes an optional 3rd parameter (passed by reference) where the percentage difference is placed.

In your situation, the following should do:

```
// Returns true if $str1 is at least $pct similar to $str2, otherwise false.
function compare($str1, $str2, $pct)
{
    $p = 0;
    similar_text($str1, $str2, $p);
    
    return ($p >= $pct);
}
```

Comment: I've never had to use it, but I have had to use `levenshtein()`.  The two happen to be closely related.

Comment: Thanks for `levenshtein()`, I'll need to decide if to use that or the other. Both are pretty good.